# Renaming a Graph in Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I am new on Python and I am trying to learn Networkx ( https://networkx.github.io/  )

I am trying to run a basic a code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()

G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_node(4)
G.add_node(5)
G.add_node(6)
G.add_node(7)

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(3,4)
G.add_edge(4,5)
G.add_edge(5,6)
G.add_edge(6,7)
G.add_edge(7,1)

G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(1,5)
G.add_edge(1,6)
G.add_edge(1,7)

G.add_edge(2,4)
G.add_edge(2,5)
G.add_edge(2,6)
G.add_edge(2,7)

G.add_edge(3,5)
G.add_edge(3,6)
G.add_edge(3,7)

G.add_edge(4,6)
G.add_edge(4,7)

G.add_edge(5,7)

nx.draw(G)

plt.savefig("graph1.png")
plt.show()
```

and this is the graph generated:

[image]

The problem comes when trying to add names to the nodes. I am running the next code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()

G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_node(4)
G.add_node(5)
G.add_node(6)
G.add_node(7)

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(3,4)
G.add_edge(4,5)
G.add_edge(5,6)
G.add_edge(6,7)
G.add_edge(7,1)

G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(1,5)
G.add_edge(1,6)
G.add_edge(1,7)

G.add_edge(2,4)
G.add_edge(2,5)
G.add_edge(2,6)
G.add_edge(2,7)

G.add_edge(3,5)
G.add_edge(3,6)
G.add_edge(3,7)

G.add_edge(4,6)
G.add_edge(4,7)

G.add_edge(5,7)

names = {1:"Central",2:"South",3:"North",4:"East",5:"West",6:"Up",7:"Down"}
H=nx.relabel_nodes(G,names)

nx.draw(H)

plt.savefig("graph1.png")
plt.show()
```

and the resulted graph is this one:

[image]

How can I add names to the nodes? I am using python 3.8 and Networkx 2.4

Comment: use nx.draw_networkx instead nx.draw

Comment: it is working, thanks

Comment: no problem. btw, you can generate the same graph with `nx.complete_graph(7)`

Comment: @warped do you know how can I change the colours of the edges? I wasn't trying to plot just a complete graph, I was trying to plot a complete graph but with edges of different colours

Comment: see the edit to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `nx.draw(H, with_labels=True)`,
Or `nx.draw_networkx(H)`, which has `with_labels=True` as default.

[documentation of nx.draw](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw):

> draw(G, pos=None, ax=None, **kwds)
>
> [...]
>
> kwds (optional keywords) – See networkx.draw_networkx() for a description of optional keywords.

[documentation of nx.draw_networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx)

> draw_networkx(G, pos=None, arrows=True, with_labels=True, **kwds)
>
> [...]
>
> with_labels (bool, optional (default=True)) – Set to True to draw labels on the nodes.

edit:

draw edges with different colors:

check out the function [nx.draw_networkx_edges](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html)

relevant attributes:

```
edge_color (color string, or array of floats) – Edge color. Can be a single color 
format string (default=’r’), or a sequence of colors with the same length as edgelist. If numeric values are specified they will be mapped to colors using the edge_cmap and edge_vmin,edge_vmax parameters.
style (string) – Edge line style (default=’solid’) (solid|dashed|dotted,dashdot)
alpha (float) – The edge transparency (default=1.0)
cmap (edge) – Colormap for mapping intensities of edges (default=None)
edge_vmin,edge_vmax (floats) – Minimum and maximum for edge colormap scaling (default=None)
```

So, you can make a list of strings:

```
colors = ['red'] * len(G.edges()

pos = nx.spring(layout(G))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edge_color=colors)
```

or use numbers and a colormap:

```
colors = [np.random.rand() for e in G.edges()]
pos = nx.spring(layout(G))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edge_color=colors, cmap='viridis')
```